# Check box based filtering of SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: checkbox, filter, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 list with one of the column as "Current Status" that holds values like "Not Started", "In Progress", "Completed" and few more.
I already have a Search box (JavaScript code in CEWP) where we can filter list items based on text string entered. It works fine. However, since the list is getting larger day by day, the search functionality is getting slower. Around 80% of the items in the list are with "Completed" status. So, we want to have a functionality where we can include or exclude the Completed items from search as required. This is because sometimes we still need to perform a search including "Completed" items as well.

=> My goal is to have a check box labeled "Completed". The function of check box would be:
***When Checked - The SharePoint list will Include "Completed" items** 
(Other items with Current Status "Not Started", "In Progress" etc should be there always)

***When Unchecked - SharePoint list will Exclude "Completed" Items but keep others**

Also, the search box I already have should continue to work.

I tried to search for this, however, couldn't find it. I am not very good with JavaScript, however, if someone can help with code that can directly be implemented on CEWP, it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you should resist the urge to write your own code when you can leverage an out of the box feature.

For a list filter, I recommend you [define a new SharePoint view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9) that filters out the "Completed" items.  Call this view "Current Items" and make this the default view.  Then your users can flip between the default view and the All Items view to view each list.

Search has advanced with the later versions of SharePoint (2013, 2016 and Online).  The [search box above the list](https://www.eliostruyf.com/making-columns-searchable-for-the-list-or-library-searchbox/) is a powerful list only search that can be leveraged to search your list. You will not see a performance degradation with large lists like you are seeing with your Javascript.

Comment: Adding view is one the options but then flipping between views isn't very convenient when you want to have a look at all search items of a particular Category ( like Testing or Development or Support). Unfortunately, we still are on SP 2010 with no default search available for list.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this question at:  sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you :)